# Whitelist nested params with params.permit in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Considering a param-set like this:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(
 {sync:{ 
   "id1":[{error:"1", balance:"1"}], 
   "id2":
       [
         {error:"2", balance:"2"},
         {error:"22", balance:"22"},
         ....
         {error:"n", balance:"n"}
       ]
   } 
  }
)
```

How is it possible to white list the nested keys "id1" and "id2"

```
params.require(:sync)
=> {"1"=>[{"error"=>"1", "balance"=>"1"}], "2"=>[{"error"=>"2",   "balance"=>"2"}]}
```

This is ok but now i would like to go deeper. In this hash i would like to get each array from the value by the key. How can i do that?

```
>> params.require(:sync).permit(:id)
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2
=> {}
```

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) contains several useful suggestions for a variety of different scenarios. From the looks of it, the more recent comments (Aug 2015 onward) are most relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the way that id2 is defined, but i don't know if you can manipulate the way that you recieve the data.

You should try set the white list like this:

```
params.require(:sync).permit({id1: [:error, :balance]}, {id2: [{:error, :balance},{:error, :balance},{:error, :balance}]})
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer!! I tried also the version with two symbols in the hashs like {:error, :balance} but i throws me the `SyntaxError: (irb):102: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>or, :balance]}, {id2: [{:error, :balance},{:error, :balance}` Also i need to make it more generic since i dont know now many objects oen array will contain. Unfortunatelly i cannot change to received format :(

Comment: I think that the model isn't well designed, you can't have infinite attributes, that should be in a detail table (or detail model) that it should be a child from your original model. And you should receive that data in some params or something and then reallocate it into the respective tables.